# Spring Boot 1.4 test loading yaml file from main resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

Before migrating our `Spring Boot 1.3` application to `1.4`, when running integration tests, we used to load our `application-test.yml` file from `src/main/resources/config/` folder which would override properties from an `application.yml` file that was loaded from `src/test/resources/config/` folder.

However, with the new version of `Spring Boot` and its test suite it seems that while bootstrapping the application for testing, it no longer checks the resources folder under `src/main`. It instead only checks the `resources` that are location under `src/test/` and is looking for `.yml` files only under that folder's `config/` folder.

Is there a way to tell `Spring Boot` that it should be looking for `.yml` files under both `resources` folders?

Comment: I am running Spring Boot 1.4 and it is picking up my properties file in src/main/resources no problem.  What annotations are you using on your Test classes?

Comment: I don't want it to pick up the basic `application.properties` but the specific `application-PROFILE.yml` file. I'm running `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class), @SpringBootTest(Application.class), @ActiveProfiles("test")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to have fully separated resources. Definitely, you should think about that. But, cut the long story short, you could try to do something like this:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = {
   "classpath:test.yml",
   "classpath:test-override.yml" })
```

If you have `*.yml`, then don't forget to declare the following line above your class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```